# Keyboard not working correctly in VsCode on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

## VSCode Key Mapping Issue on Linux ARM64

### Issue Description

After updating to VSCode version 1.85.0 on a Linux ARM64 system, certain keys exhibit unexpected behavior. For instance, inputting '5' acts as a backspace, and '6' functions as a spacebar.

### Version Information

- Operating System: Linux
- Architecture: Arm64
- VSCode Version: 1.85.0

### Problematic Key Behavior

- Typing '5' results in a backspace action.
- Typing '6' leads to a spacebar action.

### Request for Assistance

If anyone has encountered and resolved a similar issue or has insights into a possible solution, your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your support.

I tried to disable all extensions in vscode,but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running `Developer: Inspect Key Mappings` in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.